# How to change the access mode of PVC in open shift

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, ceph

How I will be able to change the access mode in the persistent volume claim access mode? currently it is showing as RWO, and I need to change it as RWX?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an addition to P Ekambaram, you can do it using this commands:

*Note that this is instruction for Kubernetes, but I don't think it should be any different in OpenShift - looking at the OpenShift documentation you might need to replace `kubectl` with `oc`.

`kubectl get PV`

```
NAME         CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS      CLAIM   STORAGECLASS    REASON   AGE
my_pv          50Gi       RWX            Delete           Available           local-storage            2d22h
```

`kubectl edit pv my_pv`

And change to desired access mode:

`accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany`

You can edit most of the Kubernetes Objects in similar way.

Answer (score 6):

`accessModes` in PersistenceVolumeClaim (PVC) is an **immutable field** and **cannot be changed once applied**. Even though you can change the bounded PersistentVolume (PV) `accessModes` using the same way as suggested by @aurelius which will automatically updated PVC `accessModes`

Answer (score 1):

There are three types of access modes supported in kubernetes

1. RWO - ReadWriteOnce
2. ROX - ReadOnlyMany
3. RWX - ReadWriteMany

You should be updating the access mode in PersistentVolume as shown below

```
    accessModes:
      - ReadWriteMany
```